# efficient way of writing a python function

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
def getObj(self, x,y,z):

    sheet = self.sheet
    is_flag = sheet[FLAGTYPE]

    if is_flag:
        lines = adlines.objects.filter(
            key="",
            msc_cd=adlines.op,
            tid=x,
            svc_beg_dt__gte=datera.start,
            svc_beg_dt__lte=datera.end
        ).exclude(ind='Y')
    else:
        lines = adlines.objects.filter(
            key="",
            msc_cd=adlines.op,
            pid=x,
            svc_beg_dt__gte=datera.start,
            svc_beg_dt__lte=datera.end
        ).exclude(ind='Y')
```

Above code is a part of the function.
I have a flag assigned it to a variable and based on flag condition the filter operation happens.
is there an efficient way of writing it ?

Comment: What's inefficient about it?

Comment: yeah, As of my knowledge it is efficient but is there any othere way like making those shorter using the is_flag

Comment: I assume you want to use some sort of ternary operator to reduce code duplication? it is possible, but not necessary. It's quite legible as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looking to remove the duplication of the filter, you can configure them as a dictionary first before

```
filter_args = {
    'key': "",
    'msc_cd': adlines.op,
    'svc_beg_dt__gte': datera.start,
    'svc_beg_dt__lte': datera.end
}

if is_flag:
    filter_args['tid'] = x
else:
    filter_args['pid'] = x

lines = adlines.objects.filter(**filter_args).exclude(ind='Y')
```

Comment: You could also shorten the if statement to `filter_args['tid' if is_flag else 'pid'] = x` but i think that looks ugly..

Comment: @kate - That was there in your original snippet, i haven't changed how it functions at all

Comment: 'ind' value doesn't pass through the functional argument. so we are excluding it at Table level..

Comment: @kate - I don't understand what you mean, but it sounds like a completely seperate problem that you should ask as a new question about with what you've tried/researched